# Add VB.NET Image object to HTML

Tags: html, vb.net, image

I'm new in VB.NET and I create an object image `Dim myimg As Image` that contains an image generated with VB.NET and showing in a picture box.
I wanna add this image to HTML like this : `Dim value$ = "<img src='myimg'>`
"
Where value is used to replace  tag in html file to show the picture generated in VB.NET

Is there a way to do this

Comment: Your source tag must have a location it won't be able to take in an object. You have to save the image first and with that location create your value$ variable.

Comment: Alternatively, you might be able to [convert the image to base64](http://www.maryor.nl/blog/tabid/268/entryid/24/convert-an-image-to-a-base64-string-and-vice-versa.aspx) and [embed it in the browser](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1207190/embedding-base64-images)

Answer (score 0):

Borrowing from [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1207190/embedding-base64-images) and [this article's](http://www.maryor.nl/blog/tabid/268/entryid/24/convert-an-image-to-a-base64-string-and-vice-versa.aspx) helper class, you can do something like this:

```
Imports System.IO
Imports System.Drawing.Imaging
Public Class ImageHelper

    ' Convert an image to a Base64 string by using a MemoryStream. Save the
    ' image to the MemoryStream and use Convert.ToBase64String to convert
    ' the content of that MemoryStream to a Base64 string.
    Public Shared Function ImageToBase64String(ByVal image As Image, _
                                               ByVal imageFormat As ImageFormat)

        Using memStream As New MemoryStream

            image.Save(memStream, imageFormat)

            Dim result As String = Convert.ToBase64String(memStream.ToArray())

            memStream.Close()

            Return result

            : End Using

    End Function

    ' Convert a Base64 string back to an image. Fill a MemorySTream based
    ' on the Base64 string and call the Image.FromStream() methode to
    ' convert the content of the MemoryStream to an image.
    Public Shared Function ImageFromBase64String(ByVal base64 As String)

        Using memStream As New MemoryStream(Convert.FromBase64String(base64))

            Dim result As Image = Image.FromStream(memStream)

            memStream.Close()

            Return result

        End Using

    End Function

End Class
```

Within a button:

```
Dim myImage As Image = Image.FromFile("C:\test.png")
Dim base64 As String = ImageHelper.ImageToBase64String(myImage, ImageFormat.Png)
WebBrowser1.DocumentText = "<img alt=""Embedded Image"" src=""data:image/png;base64," & base64 & """ />"
```